# Java, putting a JScrollList onto a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist

I am wondering if there is a way to add a JList on a JFrame with a JPanel. I am making a program and I searched all over the interwebs for an answer but I can't find one. Anyways Preferably the JList with a scrollpane (that works) if it is possible

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  JScrollPane scrollpane;
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JList list;


    String categories[] = { "1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6", "7","8", "9", "10", "11", "12" };

    list = new JList(categories);
    JScrollPane scrollpane1 = new JScrollPane(list);

    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollpane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  MyClass sl = new MyClass();
frame.setVisible(true);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setSize(300, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The errors I get is that the scroll for the JList does not appear.

Comment: `the scroll for the JList does not appear` - works fine for me - after getting rid of the "new MyClass()" statement. I have no idea why that was included in your code.

Comment: Get rid of the first call `frame.setVisible(true);`.